# No index in Eclipse CDT project checked out from SVN

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt

I have checked out a cross-compilation project from SVN on Eclipse (on a Linux system). I am unable to open a functions declaration from the functions's right-click context menu (or by pressing F3). Upon research, I found out I don't even have anything like **Index -> ..** in the project's right-click menu. I have tried a lot with the **Preferences -> C/C++ -> indexer** but no useful results. I am not using Eclipse to build it but there are no errors since I can build it using makefile

PS: Though there are a few questions with the matching title, but none of them helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution found after a million attempts. The project should be checked-out as **C/C++ project**, by selecting **import using new project wizard..** The index will NOT be available in the SVN projects checked-out directly. Hope it saves some one's time

Comment: I faced same issue as question. Although I did not check out the project as a Java(as is my case) project, rechecking it out from SVN did solve the issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Kepler SR2 on Windows 7 here.

Faced the same issue, the following sequence of inputs made it work for me:

1. Import...
2. "Checkout projects from SVN."
3. Select branch etc.
4. Check the "Check out project configured using the New Project Wizard" radio button.
5. Select "C/C++ -> C Project."
6. Pick a toolchain, doesn't matter which if you use an external one.
7. Now you can right click on the project (once fully checked out) and rebuild the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Indigo and solved it as follows (without checking out again!)

Right click on project in question and select New->Convert to a C/C++ Project

After selecting toolchain, indexing gets built automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an editor issue, rather than a project issue.

I also sometimes find the "open declaration" selection is not working. When I do, I change the following setting in the "Window" menu:

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Scalability -> UNCHECK the "Disable editor live parsing" checkbox.

After that, "hovering" over a value and "open declaration" start working.

Credit: I found this answer at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201175/

[image: open declaration issue fix]