# Can't import Guava source code into Eclipse properly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guava

#### Already tried

1. [Can I convert eclipse source folders into packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496367/can-i-convert-eclipse-source-folders-into-packages/30502689#30502689)
2. [Eclipse Open declaration in Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207074/eclipse-open-declaration-in-java-project/26661525#26661525) (results in 30,000+ compile errors)

### The problem

I got Guava source by running at the command line (got guava-20.0-SNAPSHOT):

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/google/guava.git Guava
```

Ran

```
pushd Guava
mvn install -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

from the command line successfully.

Then in Eclipse I did *File > Import... > Existing Maven Project* (*Add project(s) to working set* was checked). Everything seemed to work fine, but then when I open a file, click on a method name and press F3 ("Open Declaration") to go to the declaration of the method, I get the following error:

```
Problems opening an editor

Reason:
Guava does not exist
```

["Guava" is the Eclipse project name.]

Looks like Eclipse didn't build the project and is therefore unable to trace the source code. Can anybody tell me the proper way to import Guava code into Eclipse?

Configuration:

- Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)
- M2E
- Windows 7

Comment: Perhaps this may be some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648911/how-to-add-guava-to-eclipse-project

Comment: Can you try right clicking on the project, going to Maven and then to do "Update Project"

Comment: @JackZachTibbles That is for adding the Guava jars to a project. What I am trying to do is install/use Guava as an Eclipse project so that I can conveniently browse its code, build it, may modify and submit patches etc.

Comment: @Ferrybig unfortunately that doesn't work either. I had already tried that.